Registration process isn't working in SCORM on the production environment
I am using SCORM Cloud for integrating LMS kind of application using CF. When I working with my local, the Registration functionality working fine. When I trying it in the production environment, it is throwing an 500 error.
This is the code I am using.
<cfset launchLinkRequest = {
        "expiry": 120,
        "redirectOnExitUrl": "#redirectURL#",
        "tracking": true,
        "launchAuth": {
            "type": "cookies",
            "options": {
            "ipAddress": true,
            "fingerprint": true,
            "expiry": 0,
            "slidingExpiry": 0
            }
        }
    }
/>
    
<cfhttp url="#scormBaseUrl#/registrations/#registrationId#/launchLink" method="POST" result="launchResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#authHeader#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">

    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(launchLinkRequest)#">
</cfhttp> 

Getting this API issue in production environment, but in localhost it is working fine. This is the only issue I am getting while running it on the production site. Any folks faced this kind of issue?


The filecontent from the struct dump looks like an internal server error response from the server with an error ID at the end. Are you dumping the launchResult?

Yes, it is from API response.

Is it possible your dev environment IP is whitelisted, while your production IP is not?

No @mykaf, dev environment is just localhost, I dont think we need to whitelist any of them local/prod.

Try creating a cfm template in production, e.g. named dumprequestdata.cfm that dumps all request parameters with
writeDump(GetHTTPRequestData()) and direct your production and localhost request the that debugging cfm template to compare the received request data of both cfhttp.

I am getting same kind of data in production like an internal server error. but in dev it throws proper data.

Sorry, what do you mean by "throws" proper data? We typically use "throw" for errors.

it is "shows", mistakenly typed "throws" :)

I finally fixed this issue. But I am not sure why this is working this way. I have added the "body" value directly to the cfhttpparam and it worked in the prod environment without any API error.
<cfhttp url="#scormBaseUrl#/registrations/#registrationId#/launchLink" method="POST" result="launchResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#authHeader#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">

    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="{
        'expiry': 120,
        'redirectOnExitUrl': '#redirectURL#',
        'tracking': true,
        'launchAuth': {
            'type': 'cookies',
            'options': {
            'ipAddress': true,
            'fingerprint': true,
            'expiry': 0,
            'slidingExpiry': 0
            }
        }
    }">
</cfhttp> 


This is interesting; I'm seeing that you are NOT using serializeJSON() in this version. It makes me wonder if you may have "Prefix serialized JSON with" turned on in your settings in your production environment.

Yes @mykaf I've checked the admin, it seems that is enabled!

One option would be to turn that off. Another would be to remove the extra characters after serialization, but before sending it.  Or just stick with this solution where you don't serialize it.

Yeah, not serializing it. If I update the settings there might be code changes needs to be done in other files or probably errors. I dont want to take the risk. ty!

Sounds like a plan; that setting is a security feature. Might be a good idea to mirror it on dev, though, too.
